# Reading Binary file's in JAVA

Tags: java, file, io, binary, data-storage

Ok so I'm learning to write and read binary file in java and this is the method I get suggested everywhere I google
Here's the weighting class

```
    public Writer(String fileName, String text) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream output = null;
        try{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName, true));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception!!");
            System.exit(0);
        }//THE TEXT HERE IS "test"
        output.writeChars(text);
        output.close();
        System.out.println("Successful writing!");
    }
```

Here's the reading Class

```
    public Reader(String fileName) throws IOException {
         ObjectInputStream in = null;
         try {
             in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             System.out.println("File Not found!");
             System.exit(0);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("IO Exception!!");
             System.exit(0);
         }
         int i;
         while ((i = in.read()) != -1){
             System.out.print((char) i);
         }
         in.close();
    }
```

but then my output is t e s t "There are squares in between each char"

Comment: You use `writeChars` to write the characters, therefore you should use `readChar()` to read them again. The squares are probably `\0` (NUL) characters caused by the characters being written as 2 bytes each.

Comment: You are reading bytes; chars are not bytes.  That's one reason why there are different methods for reading "binary" data and "text" data.

Comment: ObjectInput/OutputStream are for java objects, also storing class information. For binary data Input/OutputStream would suffice. For structured binary data one could use a ByteBuffer or DataInput/OutputStream.

Comment: @JoopEggen could you please give a code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binary, non-text, files `DataInputStream/DataOutputStream` are more clear.

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.bin");
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos)) {
    dos.writeUTF8("La projekto celas ŝtopi breĉojn en Vikipedio");
    dos.writeInt(42);
    dos.writeDouble(Math.PI);
}

try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.bin");
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis)) {
    String s = dis.readUTF8(); // "La projekto celas ŝtopi breĉojn en Vikipedio"
    int n = dis.readInt(); // 42
    double pi = dis.readDouble() // Math.PI
}
```

`writeUTF8` writes a length, and the an UTF-8 encoded string. A Unicode format, so any script may be written. One may mix Japanese, Greek, emoticons and Bulgarian.